# Append additional value to a variable for each ID in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, random, append

I have these two carousels that randomly pick up pictures. **[[fiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/stonecold111/KU7Zx/13/)** Each of them (`#carousel1`,`#carousel2`) picks up pictures and links from their own different inner array.

My problem is that the carousels are going to have their own image paths and links to different subdomains, but the script uses actual paths ("url" and "pic") in `addImage("/pic/" + images[i][0], "/url/" + images[i][1]);}`. The only solution I could come up with is using the domain as a variable

```
var domain = "www.picture.com";
```

in the place of the actual path "/pic/" and "/url/" and then appending the actual image path and link to the `domain` according to the carousel's ID. I'm not sure how to do the second part and if that's the right way to do this. Would anyone please give me some solutions?

```
function randomizeCarousel(selector, images) {
  var i, l, carousel = $(selector);

  function shuffle(images) {
    var i, shuffled = [];
    while(images.length) {
      i = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
      shuffled = shuffled.concat(images.splice(i, 1));
    }
    return shuffled;
  }

  function addImage(src, href) {
    var container = $("<div>"),
        link      = $("<a></a>").attr("href", href).appendTo(container),
        img       = $("<img/>").attr("src", src).appendTo(link);
    carousel.append(container);
  }

  images = shuffle(images.slice(0));
  for(i = 0, l = images.length; i < l; i++) {
    addImage("/pic/" + images[i][0], "/url/" + images[i][1]);
  }

  carousel.jsCarousel({
    onthumbnailclick: function(src) { load(src); },
    autoscroll:       true,
    circular:         true,
    masked:           false,
    itemstodisplay:   3,
    orientation: 'h'
  });
}

$(function () {
  randomizeCarousel("#carousel1", [...]); // add your 1st array here
  randomizeCarousel("#carousel2", [...]); // add your 2nd array here
  // ... etc.
});
```

Comment: I guess I'm not really seeing the issue in your code.. Why not just create 2 domain vars and (if different paths within domains), 2 path vars, and use them as appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var domain1,domain2,path1,path2;
  domain1 = 'http://domain.tld';
  domain2 = 'http://domain2.tld';
  path1 = domain1+"/pic/";
  path2 = domain2+"/url/";
    addImage(path1 + images[i][0], path2 + images[i][1]);
```

Comment: is there a way to assign path1 only for `#carousel1` and path2 only for `#carousel2`? From what I've understood, your suggestion only mixes the pathes all in the carousels.

Comment: I have no idea how your plugin is setup, but you should be able to either pass it as an optional parameter or set up something within the plugin itself to handle it.